# Auto-connect an iPhone to a MacBook via Bluetooth?

Tags: macos, macbook, iphone, bluetooth

My iPhone is connected to a MacBook via Bluetooth. But after waking up the MacBook from standby, they do not reconnect automatically. Instead, just an error message is shown indicating that the Bluetooth connection has been lost.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/98806/how-to-script-bluetooth-on-off-and-tethering-on-snow-leopard